# Drupal 7 Artisteer generated theme fatal error with media gallery

Tags: 7, media, theming

Before I start, I know that some of you may have your opinions on Artisteer, and I respect that it may not be the best way to create a theme, especially for Drupal 7, but to be truthful, I have no coding knowledge of Drupal; so I would ask politely you could focus on the following problem rather than commenting your opinions, please...

I am trying to create a website using Drupal 7 and the Media Gallery module. All goes perfectly when I am using an 'out of the box' theme, but when I set my Artisteer generated theme as default and navigate to '/galleries', the page loads as text only and I recieve the following error at the very bottom of the page (there is content above):

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/accusername/public_html/D7GFx/sites/all/themes/D7GFx/drupal7_theme_methods.php on line 229

To me, everything in the file looks fine and I can't imagine what needs changing, but of course I have not coded for Drupal before! With the blank lines included `function D7GFx_node_preview($variables) {`, is on line 229, and all seems to be well inside that function. Quite interestingly though, if I completely remove the function, the line number of the error just changes?! I hate posting massive amounts of code, but I have a feeling that to get this problem solved as soon as possible it may be nessercary to post the whole of the `drupal7_theme_methods.php`; AND I need to sort this website out as quickly as I possibly can: so here it is:

```
<?php



/* Drupal 7 methods definitons */



function D7GFx_breadcrumb($variables) {

  $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];



  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {

    // Provide a navigational heading to give context for breadcrumb links to

    // screen-reader users. Make the heading invisible with .element-invisible.

    $output = '<h2 class="element-invisible drew-postheader">' . t('You are here') . '</h2>';



    $output .= '<div class="breadcrumb drew-postcontent">' . implode(' » ', $breadcrumb) . '</div>';

    return $output;

  }

}



/**

 * Returns HTML for a button form element.

 *

 * @param $variables

 *   An associative array containing:

 *   - element: An associative array containing the properties of the element.

 *     Properties used: #attributes, #button_type, #name, #value.

 *

 * @ingroup themeable

 */

function D7GFx_button($variables) {

  $element = $variables['element'];

  $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'submit';

  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'value'));



  $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-' . $element['#button_type'] . ' drew-button';

  if (!empty($element['#attributes']['disabled'])) {

    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-button-disabled';

  }



  return '<span class="drew-button-wrapper">'.

    '<span class="drew-button-l"></span>'.

    '<span class="drew-button-r"></span>'.

    '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />'.

    '</span>';

}



/**

 * Override or insert variables into the page template.

 */

function D7GFx_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

  $vars['tabs'] = menu_primary_local_tasks();

  $vars['tabs2'] = menu_secondary_local_tasks();

}



/**

 * Returns HTML for a single local task link.

 *

 * @param $variables

 *   An associative array containing:

 *   - element: A render element containing:

 *     - #link: A menu link array with 'title', 'href', and 'localized_options'

 *       keys.

 *     - #active: A boolean indicating whether the local task is active.

 *

 * @ingroup themeable

 */

function D7GFx_menu_local_task($variables) {

  $link = $variables['element']['#link'];

  $link_text = $link['title'];



  if (!empty($variables['element']['#active'])) {

    // Add text to indicate active tab for non-visual users.

    $active = '<span class="element-invisible">' . t('(active tab)') . '</span>';



    // If the link does not contain HTML already, check_plain() it now.

    // After we set 'html'=TRUE the link will not be sanitized by l().

    if (empty($link['localized_options']['html'])) {

      $link['title'] = check_plain($link['title']);

    }

    $link['localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;

    $link_text = t('!local-task-title!active', array('!local-task-title' => $link['title'], '!active' => $active));

  }



  //added drew-class

  $link['localized_options']['attributes']['class'] = array('drew-button');



  return '<li>' .

      '<span class="drew-button-wrapper">'.

      '<span class="drew-button-l"></span>'.

      '<span class="drew-button-r"></span>'.

      l($link_text, $link['href'], $link['localized_options']) .

      "</span></li>\n";

}



/**

 * Returns HTML for a feed icon.

 *

 * @param $variables

 *   An associative array containing:

 *   - url: The url of the feed.

 *   - title: A descriptive title of the feed.

 */

function D7GFx_feed_icon($variables) {

  $text = t('Subscribe to @feed-title', array('@feed-title' => $variables['title']));

  return l(NULL, $variables['url'], array('html' => TRUE, 'attributes' => array('class' => array('feed-icon', 'drew-rss-tag-icon'), 'title' => $text)));

}



/**

 * Returns HTML for a node preview for display during node creation and editing.

 *

 * @param $variables

 *   An associative array containing:

 *   - node: The node object which is being previewed.

 *

 * @ingroup themeable

 */

function D7GFx_node_preview($variables) {

  $node = $variables['node'];



  $output = '<div class="preview">';



  $preview_trimmed_version = FALSE;



  $elements = node_view(clone $node, 'teaser');

  $trimmed = drupal_render($elements);

  $elements = node_view($node, 'full');

  $full = drupal_render($elements);



  // Do we need to preview trimmed version of post as well as full version?

  if ($trimmed != $full) {

    drupal_set_message(t('The trimmed version of your post shows what your post looks like when promoted to the main page or when exported for syndication.<span class="no-js"> You can insert the delimiter "&lt;!--break--&gt;" (without the quotes) to fine-tune where your post gets split.</span>'));

    $preview_trimmed_version = t('Preview trimmed version');

    $output .= <<< EOT

<div class="drew-post">

        <div class="drew-post-body">

    <div class="drew-post-inner drew-article">



<div class="drew-postcontent">



      <h3>

      $preview_trimmed_version

      </h3>



    </div>

    <div class="cleared"></div>





    </div>



            <div class="cleared"></div>

        </div>

    </div>



EOT;

    $output .= $trimmed;



    $preview_full_version = t('Preview full version');

    $output .= <<< EOT

<div class="drew-post">

        <div class="drew-post-body">

    <div class="drew-post-inner drew-article">



<div class="drew-postcontent">



      <h3>

      $preview_full_version

      </h3>



    </div>

    <div class="cleared"></div>





    </div>



            <div class="cleared"></div>

        </div>

    </div>



EOT;



    $output .= $full;

  }

  else {

    $output .= $full;

  }

  $output .= "</div>\n";



  return $output;

}



/**

 * Return a Artisteer themed set of links.

 *

 * @param $content

 *   An object with node content.

 * @return

 *   A string containing an unordered list of links.

 */

function art_links_woker_D7($content) {

  $result = '';

  if (!isset($content['links'])) return $result;

  foreach (array_keys($content['links']) as $name) {

    $$name = & $content['links'][$name];

    if (isset($content['links'][$name]['#links'])) {

      $links = $content['links'][$name]['#links'];

      if (is_array($links)) {

        $output = get_links_html_output_D7($links);

        if (!empty($output)) {

            $result .= (empty($result)) ? $output : '&nbsp;|&nbsp;' . $output;

        }

      }

    }

  }



$terms = get_terms_D7($content);

  if (!empty($terms)) {

  ob_start();?>

   <?php

  $result .= ($result == '') ? ob_get_clean() : '&nbsp;|&nbsp;' . ob_get_clean();

  $result .= '<div class="drew-tags">' . render($terms) . '</div>';

  }





  return $result;  

}



function get_terms_D7($content) {

    $result = NULL;

    foreach (array_keys($content) as $name) {

        $$name = & $content[$name];

        $field_type = isset($content[$name]['#field_type']) ? $content[$name]['#field_type'] : NULL;

        if ($field_type == null || $field_type != "taxonomy_term_reference") continue;

        $result = $content[$name];

    }

    return $result;

}



function get_links_html_output_D7($links) {

    $output = '';

    $num_links = count($links);

    $index = 0;



    foreach ($links as $key => $link) {

      $class = array($key);



      // Add first, last and active classes to the list of links to help out themers.

      if ($index == 0) {

        $class[] = 'first';

      }

      if ($index == $num_links) {

        $class[] = 'last';

      }

      if (isset($link['href']) && ($link['href'] == $_GET['q'] || ($link['href'] == '<front>' && drupal_is_front_page()))

          && (empty($link['language']) || $link['language']->language == $language_url->language)) {

        $class[] = 'active';

      }



      $link_output = '';



      if (isset($link['href'])) {

        // Pass in $link as $options, they share the same keys.

        $link_output = l($link['title'], $link['href'], $link);

      }

      elseif (!empty($link['title'])) {

        // Some links are actually not links, but we wrap these in <span> for adding title and class attributes.

        if (empty($link['html'])) {

          $link['title'] = check_plain($link['title']);

        }

        $span_attributes = '';

        if (isset($link['attributes'])) {

          $span_attributes = drupal_attributes($link['attributes']);

        }

        $link_output = '<span' . $span_attributes . '>' . $link['title'] . '</span>';

      }



if (strpos ($key, "comment") !== FALSE) {



          if ($index > 0 && !empty($link_output) && !empty($output)) {

          $output .= '&nbsp;|&nbsp;';

        }

        ob_start();?>

         <?php

        $output .= ob_get_clean();

        $output .= $link_output;

        $index++;

        continue;

        }



if ($index > 0 && !empty($link_output) && !empty($output)) {

          $output .= '&nbsp|&nbsp';

        }

        ob_start();?>

         <?php

        $output .= ob_get_clean();

        $output .= $link_output;

        $index++;





    }

    return $output;

 }
```

Once again, sorry for the amount of code. You may not even need to see it but I just want to cover everything, so that I can find the solution to my problem in optimum time!

Many Thanks in Advance,

Andy

Comment: The problem seems to be in that function: D7GFx_node_preview($variables) But i dont know where exactly, do you have modify some function in this file or anything in your theme directory?
Sorry...

Comment: @gbwebdservice It does seem to be in that function, but I can't say that for definate as the error line just changes when I completely remove that function! This is way I have asked here: Can someone please try to help me as soon as possible (even if it's not a garenteed solution)! No offense gbwebservice, but you haven't really helped at all, I appreciate your comment though -you obviously want to help!

Comment: What is line 229 ?

Comment: @tostinni, did I not make it clear in my original question? "With the blank lines included `function D7GFx_node_preview($variables) {`, is on line 229," - directly from my question! God, I think everybodies trying to get me excited and/or keep me waiting!

Comment: Sorry for the TLDR syndrome. Can you make a `dpm($variables);`  (using [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel)) just after line 229 to inspect the content of $variables ?

Comment: @tostinni, apologies for 'sharpness' and my little rant, etc! I will see to doing that and posting the results as soon as possible, but I'm a little busy doing something else at the minute. I will try to post them before the day is out though, as I really need to get this problem solved before tommorrow night!

Comment: This wasn't so sharp, just my reading was lacking attention ;)

Comment: Okay,I just thought I was a bit rude that's all! Please see my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologise profusely to anyone who has tried to help me, or to anyone who has even looked at this question. I don't know why, but when I oppened the file today to add `dpm($variables)` after line 229, I found that line 299 was `$field_type = isset($content[$name]['#field_type']) ? $content[$name]['#field_type'] : NULL;}` as oppossed to `function D7GFx_node_preview($variables) {`, which would explain alot.

There, I found and used [this](http://www3.artisteer.com/?post_id=161292&p=forum_post&topicsPage=2&forum_id=22) post on the Artisteer forums, which has worked a treat!

Again, I can't imagine what's happened and why I got the wrong line, but #### happens! Sorry to everyone, especially tostinni! I feel so guilty now, you even asked what was on that line. I know it's no excuse, but I was very tired and stressed when I replied to you comment!

With Thanks and Kind Regards,

Andy